# Are all PDF readers compatible with PDF/A

Tags: pdf, scanner, file-format, documents, digitization

I was exploring the setting for my printer/scanner, and there is an option to make all scans PDF/A Compliant. Having never heard of this, I looked it up.

I understand that PDF/A is a method of saving PDF files with no external references, to ensure long term support of data storage, but is it still a normal PDF file that all programs can read, or is there something that could cause some software to not open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I overlooked [this page on the PDF Association website](https://www.pdfa.org/pdfa-faq/) when I was googling PDF/A. It clearly states

```
Do I have to purchase an application to display PDF/A files?

No. All PDF viewers are capable of displaying PDF/A files.
```

Answer (score 2):

Any statement about *all* things (e.g. *all* PDF readers) is unprovable. However, it would seem sensible that including information such as fonts and images *within* a document, i.e., [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A), is **more likely to be readable**: it prevents issues such as a font not being installed, or an image being taken offline.

However, you can test this assumption. Produce a document and try opening it in some common free PDF readers:

- [PDF-XChange Viewer Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdf-xchange-portable)
- [Sumatra PDF Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/sumatra_pdf_portable)
- [Nitro PDF Reader](https://www.gonitro.com/pdf-reader)
- Of course, [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC](https://get.adobe.com/reader/) (If you need to install this, be sure to uncheck any of the additional gratuitous superfluous software that you *don't* want installed.)

Comment: Cool. I will check that out. But just so I am clear, it is still the same as a normal PDF file, just with stuff built in right?

Comment: Apparently -- actually, it's more like a normal PDF with certain "extras" Adobe created forbidden, because it might break other readers, from the Wikipedia description.